# Is it wise to convert from full time to part time master by research

Tags: masters, part-time

I supposed to finish my master at the end of this year. However it looks like I'm going to extend for another semester, which mean my scholarship will also end and I have to self sponsor myself for the tuition fee. Research grant also will end and I have no allowance for next semester. I'll not have any financial source after that.

My plan is to convert the mode and apply a job near my college so I can afford to live and pay the tuition fee. However if I apply for part time mode, the time for graduation will be extend to another 1.5 years. 
Further planning is I'll try hard for another 1.5 years to get my master converted to PHD while working.

Comment: Don't convert. Stick with this short term pain. Full-time has its own value.

Comment: Have you considered trying to get a loan to pay your tuition and living expenses for one more semester of full-time study?  This may also save you money in the long run, if one semester full-time is less than three semesters part-time.

Comment: Agreed, get a loan.  You should be able to pay it off pretty quick once you start working.

Comment: Loan. Ok I never think about that because I really want to avoid any debt since I already got one (degree loan). But it looks like a better option compare to converting to part time mode. Thank you everyone.